# What's the best way to test the leaderboard

Tags: ps4, rec-room

I'm aware there is some sort of delay on the leader board, but I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to test circuits involving leaderboards. I'm wanting to make sure it is counting everything correctly, but it is difficult to audit due to the delay.

Could someone also specify exactly how long the delay is and/or what triggers the leaderboard to update.

Cheers!

Comment: If any of the answers below satisfies you, consider accepting one so that we can keep track of questions that still need good answers ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the leaderboard display lags significantly, sometimes requiring a new instance completely in order to see updated values, the `Get Leaderboard Stat` chip will get updated values as soon as they're stored in the backend. This only takes a few seconds at most, so the best way to test leaderboard circuits is to setup some `Get Leaderboard Stat` chips connected to buttons such that you can press the button each time you want to check your stats.

I don't know all of the triggers that cause the leaderboard prop to update, but it seems to prefer updating once every 10 minutes or so. Creating a fresh instance of the room  (i.e. go to your dorm and then back to a private instance of the room) will refresh the leaderboard.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is a local cache, thus, the Get Leaderboard Stat chip should give you the correct result right after it has been set with the Set Leadboard Stat chip (I'm not sure whether it is in the next tick, but it might be). The synchronization with the server is only for the leaderboard display and for the case that a player goes to another instance of the same room or a subroom. Thus, you should always use the Get Leaderboard Stat for debugging and wait a few minutes in cases that involve room changes.